# Is interferometry with variable wavelength/baseline/resolution possible?

Tags: interferometry

The angular resolution $R$ of a telescope array with baseline $B$ at wavelength $\lambda$ is
$$ R=\frac{\lambda}{B} \;.$$
As far as I understand, interferometers like VLBI operate at a single wavelength. But is it possible to do interferometry when one of these quantities changes with time?

For example, if the target we point the telescope array at is coming towards us with some peculiar velocity, its diameter changes with time. Since we can define the visibility function as
$$ 
 V(B)=\int I(x) e^{-2\pi i B\cdot x}
$$
in which we relate the vector baseline $B$ to the image coordinate $x$, shouldn't the baseline change with time?

I was also intrigued by [this paper (pdf)](https://opticaapplicata.pwr.edu.pl/files/pdf/1987/no1/optappl_1701p47.pdf) about variable-wavelength interferometry, but I have only found theoretical papers so far. Do actual experiments like these exist?